# Example of compact upper semicontinuous map

Tags: analysis, multivalued-functions

can any one give me an exemple of compact multivalued upper semicontinuous maps in $L^{2}$ ?
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

$S^1 \to \Bbb C : z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$ is perhaps the simplest.

Comment: @Anonymous - they asked for an example of a compact multivalued upper semicontinuous $L^2$ map. This is an example of a compact multivalued continuous (therefore upper semi-continuous and because the domain is compact, $L^2$) map. Kindly explain to me how this does not provide an answer!